# Is quote in Lisp/Scheme same as a string?

Tags: scheme, lisp

There are already many questions regarding quote in Lisp, and I understand that it doesn't evaluate the expression. But I haven't seen its comparison to a string.

Is the quote same as a string?
If not, how are they different?

Comment: The relationship between quasiquotation with S-expr and string substitution is explored in https://3e8.org/pub/scheme/doc/Quasiquotation%20in%20Lisp%20(Bawden).pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lisp:

```
* (type-of "a b c")
(SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (5))
* (type-of '(a b c))
CONS
* (type-of "(a b c)")
(SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (7))
```

A string is always an object of some `string` type. A string always evaluates to itself.

The `quote` operator returns the quoted object - whatever that object may be: a `string`, a `number`, a `symbol`, a list made of `cons` cells, ...

```
CL-USER 2 > '"a b c"
"a b c"

CL-USER 3 > '3
3

CL-USER 4 > 'abc
ABC

CL-USER 5 > '(a b c)
(A B C)
```

Comment: I see. So if compared with C, a character array `"int plus_one(int i) {return i+1;}"` if it's a string, it's always a static thing wherever it's passed, but if it's a quote, it will be executable! So in this sense, is quote like a pointer in C?

Comment: @WeiHuang: it's just the same thing. `quote` just returns its argument as it is.

Comment: Does it mean it's more like macro in C: pure text replacement?

Comment: No, it's the data itself. Not text.  Lisp is different from C and no model for it.

Answer (score 1):

[`quote`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm) is a special operator.
[`string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_string.htm) is a class (the symbol [`string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_string.htm) also names a function).
They have nothing in common.

[Syntactically](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_.htm), both 
[single quote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dc.htm) and [double quote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_de.htm) are 
[Standard Macro Characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_d.htm).
However, the "similarity" ends here.

- [Single quote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dc.htm) quotes an *expression*, and does not require a closing
  quote precisely because the expression must have balanced parentheses.
- [Double quote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_de.htm) quotes *text*, and does require a closing quote.

E.g., `"((("` works (lisp reader returns a string of length 3) but `'(((` does not (the reader signals an error).

You should get a Lisp book (e.g.,
[acl](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html) or
[pcl](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)) and work through it. 
It will be much more productive.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. I didn't mean the function or operator `quote` or function `string`.  I meant the *thing* after quoted by `'`, and the *thing* enclosed by `"`. The latter is clearly the string same as other languages, the former seems similar to me.

Comment: @WeiHuang What's important is not necessarily how they are similar, but how they are different. You can quote arbitrary lisp values and manipulate them as a tree, etc.

Comment: @WeiHuang: I expanded the answer to address your clarification.

Comment: Thanks @sds for explaining the syntax details.

Answer (score 1):

A single quote followed by the written representation of a value will produce that value:

Example: `'(1 x "foo")` will produce a value that prints as `(1 x "foo")`.

Suppose now that I don't want a literal symbol `x` in the list. I have a variable `x` in my program, and I want to insert the value to which `x`.

To mark that I want the value of `x` rather than the symbol `x`, I insert a comma before `x`:

```
'(1 ,x "foo")
```

It won't work as-is though - I now get a value that has a literal comma as well as a symbol `x`. The problem is that quote does not know about the comma convention.

Backtick or backquote knows about the comma-convention, to that will give the correct result:

```
> `(1 ,x "foo")
(1 3 "foo")          ; if the value of x is 3
```

Now strings and symbols aren't the same thing. The difference is that symbols are *interned*. It means that there is only one copy of the symbols at a time.

In `(list 'foo 'foo)` you will get a list which contains the same symbol twice.
In other words `(eq? 'foo 'foo)` is true.

On the other hand in `(list (string #\a) (string #\a))` you produce two strings each containing the character a. However you get two different strings. So mutating one of the strings won't change the other.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know this _quasiquotation_.

Answer (score 1):

Quotation means to return the symbolic expression itself, without evaluating it.

Example:

```
  '1 => 1

  '"abc" => "abc"

  'sym => sym        << here the sym is not evaluated as a variable,
                        but it is returned the symbol itself.

  '(+ 1 1) => (+ 1 1)
```

Quotation makes the link (similarity) between code and data.

You can also create code:

```
(list 'quote '+ 1 2 3) => '(+ 1 2 3)
```

Your question would be more interesting if you asked if a symbol is also a string.  The answer is no.

You should read and understand what means [`symbolic expressions`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).

Comment: yes, with the help of the answers, I realized what confused me was actually comparison between a symbol and a string. I know the wiki page but never carefully read it. I'll do that.